# gawk sub() with ampersand and toupper() not working

Tags: awk

I'm having trouble using `toupper()` inside a gawk `sub()`. I'm using the feature that `&` substitutes for the matched string.

```
$ gawk '{sub(/abc/, toupper("&")); print $0; }'
xabcx
xabcx
```

I expected:

```
xABCx
```

Variants with `toupper()` but without `&` and with `&` but without `toupper()` work:

```
$ gawk '{sub(/abc/, toupper("def")); print $0; }'
xabcx
xDEFx

$ gawk '{sub(/abc/, "-&-"); print $0; }'
xabcx
x-abc-x
```

It fails similarly with `tolower()`. Am I misunderstanding something about how `&` works?
(Tested with gawk 3.1.x and the latest, 4.1.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what's going on: the `toupper` function is being evaluated **first**, before sub constructs the replacement string.

So you get

```
sub(/abc/, toupper("def")) => sub(/abc/, "DEF")
```

and the not-so-useful

```
sub(/abc/, toupper("&")) => sub(/abc/, "&")
```

To get your desired results, you have to extract the match first, upper-case it, and *then* perform the substitution:

```
$ echo foobar | gawk '{sub(/o+/, toupper("&")); print}'
foobar
$ echo foobar | gawk '{
    if (match($0, /o+/, m)) {
        replacement = toupper(m[0])
        sub(/o+/, replacement)
    }
    print
}'
fOObar
```

Alternatively, you don't need the sub, you can reconstruct the record thusly:

```
echo foobar | gawk '{
    if (match($0, /o+/, m)) {
        $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) toupper(m[0]) substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}'
```

Comment: Nice detective work! I get why you've spelled it out that way but it might be worth adding that it can be reduced to `gawk 'match($0,/o+/,m){sub(/o+/,toupper(m[0]))}1'`.

Comment: @ed, I tried that, but the first `(.*)` is too greedy and slurps up all but one "o"

Comment: I'm not sure which is better - `gawk 'match($0,/o+/,m){sub(/o+/,toupper(m[0]))}1'` which makes you specify the regexp twice (a problem for complex regexps), or `gawk 'match($0,/o+/,m){sub(m[0],toupper(m[0]))}1'` which causes a problem if the regexp used in match() matches a string that itself includes RE metachars. All things considered I think your final script using substr() is the best approach as it solves both issues.

Comment: nitpick - strings in awk start at 1, not 0 so your first substr() should be `substr($0, 1, RSTART-1)`, not `substr($0, 0, RSTART-1)`. The latter only "works" because awk treats any invalid value in the 2nd arg to substr() as if it were 1.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a solution that isn't dependent on `gawk`, and one that affords you roughly the same flexibility as the `gawk` extension feature, without having to do `substr()` nonstop, then try this framework i slapped together :

It's simultaneously ***BOTH*** a regular **`FS/split()`** and a **`match()/patsplit()`** -

- if your `regex` describes the separators/delineators, then, you can find the core contents at odd-numbered indices of the array, while the `seps` reside in the even numbered ones.
- conversely, if your `regex` describes the contents themselves (same style as if you're doing **`FPAT/patsplit()`**, then access your content at even-numbered indices of the array instead

For now you'll have to customize what you wanna do with it, so I included 3 sample scenarios of what's feasible :

- up-casing only a specific string of letters (`"klm"` —> `"KLM"`)

---

```
  DEFabc2039klm8191劎xyz

  DEFabc2039 ***KLM*** 8191劎xyz
```

---

```
    function ____(__, _, ___)
    {
        if (__ !~ (_ = "klm"))
            return __
        
        gsub(_, (_ = "\1\23\3\21") ("&") _, __)
        __ = ___[_ = split(__, ___, (_)"|"(_)_)]

        while (-_ <= --_) {
            __ = ___[--_] ("" < ___[_+!!_] \
                           ? " ***" toupper(___[_+!!_]) "*** " : "") __
        }
        return __
    }
```

---

- take any chain of `ASCII` digits and substituting it with the `UTF-8` encoding of said code point (assuming you're using `gawk` in unicode mode, and that it's a valid Unicode cp to begin with, otherwise this would just print out 8-bit bytes of those same values)

  -— *the `?` isn't actually a question mark, but an intentionally placed `UTF-8 invalid` byte of `\301 \xC1`, to showcase the rest of inputs are preserved as is*

---

```
  DEF61abc5115kl?m40404劎xy567z

  DEF | 
     U+  003D |      61 ::--{ =   }- | abc | 
     U+  13FB |    5115 ::--{ ᏻ }- | kl?m | 
     U+  9DD4 |   40404 ::--{ 鷔 }- | 劎xy | 
     U+  0237 |     567 ::--{ ȷ  }- | z
```

---

```
     function ____(__, _, ___, _____)
     {
        if (__ !~ (_ = "[0-9]+")) 
            return __
        
        gsub(_, (_ = "\773\350") ("&")_, __)

        __ = ___[_ = split(__, ___, (_)"|"(_)_)]

        while (--_) {
            __ = ___[--_] " | " \
                 sprintf("\f\r\t U+%6.4X | %7d ::--{ %-3c }-",
                         _____ = ___[_ +!!_], _____, _____) " | " __
        }
        return __
    }
```

---

- take any chain of 2 or more odd `ASCII` digits, and replace it with the cube of it (up to precision limitations of your settings)

---

```
  abc123k7791lmqrstu65yx\\\173&&&&\&04z

  abc123k | "472911214671" | lmqrstu65yx\\\ | "5177717" | &&&&\&04z
```

---

```
    function ____(__, _, ___)
    {
        if (__ !~ (_ = "[13579][13579]+"))
            return __
        
        gsub(_, (_ = "\247\36\5") ("&")_, __)

        __ = ___[_ = split(__, ___, _ "|" (_) _)]

        while (--_)
            __ = ___[--_] (" | \"" (___[_+!!_]^3) "\" | ")__
        
        return __
    }
```

With efficient recycling for roles of temp variables, the 1st and 3rd versions only needed 2 extra ones on top of the mandatory one for accepting the input (`__`)

(actually more like only 1 extra one since the array one is kinda essential)

- input variable (`__`) gets immediately turned around after being split into the array, and becomes the placeholder for concatentating the output
- `___[ ]` is the array being `split()` into
- `_` is the truly agile one - in the beginning it holds the `regular expression` being matched against.

  - half-way through `gsub()` it switches role and becomes the          string of bytes for the temporary `SEP`, enabling indirect `gsub()`-ing + `split()`-ing,
  - thus refraining from contaminating the input's actual `seps`, like leading edge spaces & tabs.
  - finally, it also becomes the counter to sequentially iterate through the array, `LIFO`-style.